# Is there a word/phrase/euphemism that means "fat" that includes either the word "meat" or "flesh" (used on men)?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, euphemisms

Example sentence:

> He preferred people to call him __ instead of fat or heavy.

I thought of the word *meaty*. But I think I've never heard of a man being refereed to as "meaty" (Maybe I'm wrong?)

Comment: People are occasionally described as *meaty* meaning big, but in the sense of big with muscle (*beefy* is similar but more common)

Comment: Does it need to contain the word "meat" or "flesh"? Your example sentence would lend itself to "well-built", but that doesn't meet the criteria in your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just *fleshy* would do:

1b: marked by abundant flesh; especially: corpulent ([MW.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fleshy))

Other definitions include *plump* and *having a substantial amount of flesh*

Comment: But is that a euphemism? Would people prefer to be called "big","heavy" or "fleshy"?

Comment: ‘Well fleshed’ is used as a gentle euphemism https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/well-fleshed

Comment: @Logophile I assumed that as it's not possible to meet the first two criteria in the title simultaneously, it was only necessary to meet one (otherwise the request could be for a *euphemstic word/phrase*). That said I think *fleshy* comes between *fat* (harsh) and *heavy*  (slightly gentler).  To me, *fleshy* implies a level of comfort, perhaps from the similarity to *fleshpot*, that isn't there with *heavy* or *big*

Comment: I think more people are happy with "plump" being applied to them.  It's generally regarded as pleasant. The French even have a word "molleux" which means "pleasantly plump".

Comment: @Logophile but that doesn't include *meat* or *flesh* as asked for.

Comment: Yes. I know that's why you mentioned it in your answer but did not make it your main answer.